# not able to build string with double quotes in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to call TCL script(in shell) with arguments as:

```
 'adsp2_ia.exe -T -t "C:/build_tst.tcl filenm Release"'
```

This need to be called in matlab.

I have tried following in matlab:

```
cmd1 = 'adsp2_ia.exe -T -t ''"C:/build_tst.tcl filenm Release''"'
system(cmd)
```

gives error:

> couldn't read file
>   "'C:/build_tst.tcl":
>   no such file or directory

Where am i wrong?
Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many single quotes inside, try this:

```
cmd = 'adsp2_ia.exe -T -t "C:/build_tst.tcl filenm Release"'
system(cmd)
```

Comment: @PauAl it was stupid of me not to do that. I did it correctly, later, and  tried to delete my question but my explorer hanged. thank you anyways.